# Why when my desktop screen and mobile screen have the same resolution don't they display the same thing?

Tags: android, css, pixel, mobile-website

For example, one my desktop one of my 50px wide button is viewed on my desktop it looks like it occupies about 5% of the screen space as expected. But when viewed on my Android device with the same horizontal resolution it looks like it occupies about 15%.

Can anyone explain why this is and what I can do to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

Different displays have different pixel sizes. You hear this referenced as DPI, or dots-per-inch, which is physically how many pixels there are per inch. In your case, your desktop has smaller pixels than your Android device (higher DPI), so the 50px takes up less physical space.

You can fix this by specifying a physical size, such as `cm` or `in`. Check out the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units).

Comment: Updated answer to mention what the asker can do to get a physical size from CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Understood on the pixel size thing, but for example both screens have 1000 horizontal pixels available and an element is 100px in width it should still take up 10% of the available screen space regardless of the pixel size. Or am I missing something?

Comment: A zoom factor could contribute to it not scaling correctly. Desktop and mobile devices alike allow users to zoom in to or out of web pages, so it's possible that one or both of them are showing scaled content.