# Desktop Screen and Mobile Screen with same Resolution, but different Results

Tags: html, css, mobile, pixel, dpi

I am trying to understand why  if I have a Webseite working on 1920px width and I have smartphone with 1920px resolution, it will display different?

I found that Answer ([URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915875/why-when-my-desktop-screen-and-mobile-screen-have-the-same-resolution-dont-they)) but this confused me even more.

An Example for me:

I have a div Header which has a 100% width and this Header contains 10 images, when viewing this on Desktop everthing is fine (Desktop width 1920px) Now I am changing to my smartphone which also has a Resolution from 1920px and some of the are not in the line anymore. So why isn't that possible?

The Answer with DPI is confusing me because:

I have 2 Screens, both of them has the same Resolution. My Android has bigger Pixel than my Desktop, so how is ist possible that  they both have the same Resolution than?

If someone could explain me that or refers an article which explains that, I would be so thankful!

Markus

Comment: http://alistapart.com/article/A-PIXEL-IDENTITY-CRISIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me was simple:

Example:

Galaxy S4 Resolution (Hardware Pixel) : 1920x1680

Pixel Ratio  : 3

Galaxy S4 Optical Pixel: 640x340

Answer (score 1):

What he's saying is:

The resolution is the same but the PHYSICAL size of each pixel is different.

Let's assume your screen is **100cm** long and your smartphone is **10cm** long.
If your screen has 1920px, each one is **100**/1920= 0.052cm long.
If your smartphone has 19202px too, each one will be **10**/1920 = 0.0052cm long

I considered just one dimension to make it easier. As you can see the physical size of pixels is different and so is the result.

Now you might ask yourself "Ok, but how do I fix this?"

Well instead of saying "Make this item **10px long**"
you can say
"Make it **1cm long**"

We've seen that pixels size can change from one device to another, but physical units don't.
So **10 pixels might be longer or shorter** from device to device but **1cm is always 1cm**.

I hope i clarified your doubts! :)

Comment: well ok but would'n that mean if i have 10 images which each one has a width of 50px, that on my smarthphone the images must be tinier that on my desktop and everything should fit fine, but just smaller? Because that would be the result i would like to have.